# validation, the users input must equal to his/her account number and pin, is this the correct way? i seem to just be getting errors

Tags: java

This part of code is not in a function as I am declaring all values before they can get used by future functions.

Here is a snippet that I'm struggling with

validate if user input is correct

```
if (userinput.equals(x.indexOf("1234")) && userinput.equals(pinA.indexOf("1223")) ){
    {System.out.println(x);
    int bal = 500;
    
    System.out.println("your balance is: " + bal);
    MainMenu();
    }
// that if statement is giving me errors

//here is my variable declaration
public class SimpleBankingApp {

//declare the pins
String pinA = "1223";
int pinB = 1227;
int pinC = 7643;
int pinD = 8554;

// have the users details in strings
public String x = "1234 500";
public String b = "3546 50000";
public String d = "4253 6000";
public String t = "7722 804";

//get user input from user
static {System.out.println("enter your choice");}
Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
String userinput = a.nextLine();

if (userinput.equals(x.indexOf("1234")) && userinput.equals(pinA.indexOf("1223")) ){
{System.out.println(x);
int bal = 500;

System.out.println("your balance is: " + bal);
MainMenu();
}
```

By the declaration of the pins, I tested to see if a string variable would work hence why one of them is a string

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use indexOf() here. Just use equals like this `userinput.equals(pinA)`, also use "or"(||) instead of "and"(&&) in your if condition or use 2 user inputs if you want to compare 2 separate fields, because 1 field can't be equals to 2 different strings